# mongodump gives segmentation fault

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I have MongoDB v3.2.6 installed on my mac `macOs High Sierra v10.13.1` and I am trying to make a backup before I upgrade.

I have an instance of `$ mongod` running in one window using defaut db location and default port.

It is my local database, it is not protected by a password and does not require ssl conncetions.

I can access my databases find using `$ mongo` or Robomongo but when I run `$ mongodump` or `$ mongodump --db mydatabase` I get the following error

`[1]    1815 segmentation fault  mongodump`

**UPDATE**: I have tried to run `mongostat` and now I get the following error :

`[1]    2404 bus error  mongodump`

Here is the log I get when starting the db with `$ mongod` :

```
2017-12-25T12:36:26.642+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3216 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=MBP-de-Kevin.home
2017-12-25T12:36:26.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
2017-12-25T12:36:26.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
2017-12-25T12:36:26.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017
2017-12-25T12:36:26.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2017-12-25T12:36:26.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-12-25T12:36:26.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-12-25T12:36:26.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-12-25T12:36:26.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-12-25T12:36:26.643+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-12-25T12:36:26.644+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
2017-12-25T12:36:26.653+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2017-12-25T12:36:26.654+0000 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2017-12-25T12:36:26.674+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2017-12-25T12:36:26.675+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2017-12-25T12:36:26.894+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-12-25T12:36:26.894+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2017-12-25T12:36:26.894+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

What am I doing wrong and How can I debug?

Comment: Additional details may be important. What does your mongodump command look like? Is your mongo config set to require SSL connections? Is your database username and password protected? I would encourage you to provide these kinds of details in case this is a configuration-related issue. They should aid in narrowing down the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my questions. There is no password and ssl connections are not required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was experiencing the same problem.  I am on macOS High Sierra 10.13.3.  My mongo version was mongodb 3.2.7.  I read this in the [documentation of mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/):

```
MAC OSX SIERRA AND GO 1.6 INCOMPATIBILITY
Users running on Mac OSX Sierra require the 3.2.10 or newer version of mongodump.
```

I upgraded to mongodb 3.6.2 and I my issue was resolved.

Comment: Sounds like the most likely reason.

Comment: brew install mongodb@3.6

Answer (score 6):

I fixed my error using `brew upgrade mongodb`. Still dont know what was the issue.

That said it is better to follow one of these guide [upgrade mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-standalone/) to avoid other issues.

Comment: brew install mongodb@3.6